# Can I determine who is calling a function or instantiating a class in Java?

Tags: java, language-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, how do i find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

I'm just curious. I was requesting that feature sometimes, but then I solved it with more code. (the calling class said its name while calling the method)

Comment: Thx for the answers. Im also fine with the closing of the thread because of the duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

```
private Class getCallingClass() {
    return new SecurityManager() {
       protected Class[] getClassContext(){return super.getClassContext();} 
    }.getClassContext()[2];
}
```

OR

```
public class Foo {

    public static final void main(final String[] args) {

        test();
    }

    private static void test() {

        Throwable e = new Throwable();

        StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(elements.length > 1 ? elements[1].toString() : "(no caller)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you even need to call `fillInStackTrace`: according to the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable%28%29), the constructor calls it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using 'fake exception', even though this trick feels kinda dirty.

```
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[1]);
    }
```

`getStackTrace` returns an array of `StackTraceElement` objects, you can check [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) to see what you can do with them.

Comment: you don't need to throw it,check my answer