# How to find method name from within that method in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I was wondering if there is a way to know the method name being executed at run time?

For instance, inside a `private void doSomething (String s)` method, I'd like to know that I am executing the `doSomething (String s)` method.

Comment: This really isn't something your code should require. I'd very much advise rethinking your design so that you don't need it.

Comment: If you are inside that method you already know the name, right? :) If you want to know the caller method's name, Jigar's answer below is the one you are looking for. Just use 1 instead of 0 as index.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since JDK1.5, you don't need an Exception to get the StackTrace,
you can get it with `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`]:

```
   public class Test2 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test2().doit();
     }
     public void doit() {
        System.out.println(
           Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()); // output : doit
     }
   }
```

Comment: This is a better solution, as you don't have to create the exception to get the stack.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working for me...it prints out "getStackTrace" for me - using Java 1.5

Comment: @Zack Macomber, What is the output : `StackTraceElement [] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement s : ste) {
          System.out.println(s);
        }` , are you using a Sun JRE ?

Comment: @RealHowTo - I was able to use '[2]' instead of '[1]' to get the method name - I use IBM's RSA so I think I may be using IBM's version of Java

Comment: That's what I got - 
a) [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@429c6ae0 b) -getThreadStackTrace
 how come?

Comment: Is it always certain that I will get the name of the method at `index 1` of `stacktrace`?

Comment: @Ram swaroop, it depends on the JVM vendor (Oracle, IBM,...)

Comment: @RealHowTo Okay, so is there any universal solution to this? At least in Java 8?

Comment: I am trying to print the method name in android activity methods . I had to use 
`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()`

Comment: What is the performance implications for this? I mean, will it be better to create a string with the method name instead of using this solution? Especially when the **output depends on the JVM vendor**.

Answer (score 10):

```
System.out.println(new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
```

**Also See**

- [Can-i-determine-who-is-calling-a-function-or-instantiating-a-class-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907983/can-i-determine-who-is-calling-a-function-or-instantiating-a-class-in-java/3908024#3908024)

Comment: useGetStacktrace()[1] to get the calling methods name. A bit more useful :)

Comment: @Daniel, is that what was asked for?  Note that 1) there is no _guarantee_ that the stacktrace is accurate, and 2) that this has previously been a very expensive operation.  It should be better in recent JVM's.

Comment: Really? When would it possible that you get an inaccurate stack trace occurs? Or is it just not guaranteed you get one? I never had these problems.

Comment: It think it's important to precise that this solution is only good for JDK **>= 1.4** and **< 1.5**. For JDK **>= 1.5** you don't have to instanciate a new `Exception` each time, which saves resources (checkout *RealHowTo*'s answer above).

Answer (score -2):

```
Method lastMethodCalled = this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he was asking for. See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod())