# Any Alternative to get class Loader from of calling class {Reflection.getCallerClass(2).getClassLoader()}

Tags: java, classloader, java-8

I need to get class loader for calling class of current method in Java8 . 
But since Reflection.getCallerClass() has been removed now , can anyone suggest any other way to get classLoader of calling class?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should tell us *why* you think you need the caller’s `ClassLoader`. Otherwise it’s likely to become a typical XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, `Reflection.getCallerClass()` has been removed from Java 8 version.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640058/java-7u40-java-se-8-sun-reflect-reflection-getcallerclass) for more info.

Comment: thanks for reply .. but the other question link posted doesnt provide much info about the alternative for this.

Comment: @user3417179 i could not find either