# How to enforce some service can be called only from service layer

Tags: java, spring

I want to have some @Component beans which should be only called from @Service beans and no other bean. How can I enforce it? I don't want to change maven packaging. What about requiring running transaction? But it is only runtime not compile time check.

Answer (score 1):

Add an aspect to intercept the service methods calls.

```
@Around("execution(* MyComponent)")
public void wrapAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
{
    joinPoint.proceed(); 
}
```

See more [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/spring-aop-aspectj-example-tutorial-using-annotation-config/)

and then check caller class

```
public class KDebug {
    public static String getCallerClassName() { 
        StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (int i=1; i<stElements.length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
            if (!ste.getClassName().equals(KDebug.class.getName()) && ste.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread")!=0) {
                return ste.getClassName();
            }
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java)

Check whether the caller class has annotation

```
for (Annotation annotation : Caller.class.getAnnotations()) {
```

and find whether the caller has `@Service` annotation. If not throw an exception

Comment: Nice, but still only runtime solution.Anything that can be done for compile time check?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to do compile time check. Annotation is just a marker and indirect calls are possible.

Comment: One way, although little bit complicated is to create some compiler annotation processor. Maybe I have to wait for Java 9 modules support.