# How can I refactor a Helper class that requires a context from two different Adapters?

Tags: java, android, refactoring, adapter

I have the following Helper class that I keep in a folder alongside my adapters. The problem is there is unnecessary duplication. I need the context of either adapter, depending on where the helper is called from, i.e. from which adapter. How can I make the adapter that is being passed into the helper's constructor generic?

**Call:**

In the call, I set one of either adapter to null depending on where I am.

```
private final QuickReplyDialogHelper quickReplyDialogHelper = new QuickReplyDialogHelper(this, null);
quickReplyDialogHelper.quickReplyDialog(object);
```

**Helper:**

```
class QuickReplyDialogHelper {

    private final UserProfileAdapter userProfileAdapter;
    private final FeedAdapter feedAdapter;

    QuickReplyDialogHelper(UserProfileAdapter userProfileAdapter, FeedAdapter feedAdapter) {
        this.userProfileAdapter = userProfileAdapter;
        this.feedAdapter = feedAdapter;
    }

    void quickReplyDialog(ParseObject object) {

        if (userProfileAdapter != null) {
            CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(userProfileAdapter.getmContext());
            builder.setTitle("Quick Reply");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_quick_reply);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = builder.setItems(colors, (dialog, which) -> {
                String quickReply = null;
                if (which == 0) {
                    quickReply = "1";
                    Toast.makeText(userProfileAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (which == 1) {
                    quickReply = "2";
                    Toast.makeText(userProfileAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (which == 2) {
                    quickReply = "3";
                    Toast.makeText(userProfileAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ParseObject message = new ParseObject("Object");
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                message.put("replyAuthor", object.getParseObject(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER));
                String[] likedBy = new String[0];
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_LIKED_BY, Arrays.asList(likedBy));
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_PARSE_OBJECT_ID, object.getObjectId());
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, quickReply);
                message.saveInBackground();

            });
            builder1.show();
        }

        if (feedAdapter != null) {
            CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(feedAdapter.getmContext());
            builder.setTitle("Quick Reep");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_quick_reply);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = builder.setItems(colors, (dialog, which) -> {
                String quickReply = null;
                if (which == 0) {
                    quickReply = "1";
                    Toast.makeText(feedAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (which == 1) {
                    quickReply = "2";
                    Toast.makeText(feedAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (which == 2) {
                    quickReply = "3";
                    Toast.makeText(feedAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ParseObject message = new ParseObject("Object");
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                message.put("replyAuthor", object.getParseObject(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER));
                String[] likedBy = new String[0];
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_LIKED_BY, Arrays.asList(likedBy));
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_PARSE_OBJECT_ID, object.getObjectId());
                message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, quickReply);
                message.saveInBackground();

            });
            builder1.show();
        }


    }
}
```

---

**Ideal Call:**

```
private final QuickReplyDialogHelper quickReplyDialogHelper = new QuickReplyDialogHelper(this);
quickReplyDialogHelper.quickReplyDialog(object);
```

**Ideal Helper:**

Just one builder:

```
    CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(genericAdapter.getmContext());
    builder.setTitle("Quick Reep");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_quick_reply);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = builder.setItems(colors, (dialog, which) -> {
        String quickReply = null;
        if (which == 0) {
            quickReply = "1";
            Toast.makeText(genericAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (which == 1) {
            quickReply = "2";
            Toast.makeText(genericAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (which == 2) {
            quickReply = "3";
            Toast.makeText(genericAdapter.getmContext(), quickReply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        ParseObject message = new ParseObject("Object");
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        message.put("replyAuthor", object.getParseObject(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER));
        String[] likedBy = new String[0];
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_LIKED_BY, Arrays.asList(likedBy));
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_PARSE_OBJECT_ID, object.getObjectId());
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, quickReply);
        message.saveInBackground();


    });
    builder1.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using stacktrace to determine where the call is coming from? It might add a lot of lines to your code, but it would make it easier for you to kinda determine the destination of each call.

This link might help : 
[How to get the caller class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java)

Hope this helps.

Alternatively you could make the name of the caller a required field when constructing the object. That way your class will always know who created it, Like assigning an ID.