# In Java, is there a way to get access to an object from inside an object created/used by that class?

Tags: java, class, object

Let's say I have a class that instantiates and uses another class. From the second class, is it possible to gain access to the first one?
For example:

```
public class A {
    public B obj = new B();

    public void something() {
        b.somethingElse();
    }
}

public class B {
    public void somethingElse() {
        A owner = getCallingObject();
        //the object of class A that called b.somethingElse() is now stored in owner
    }

    public Object getCallingObject() {
        // ?????
        // returns the A that instantiated/owns this B
    }
}
```

I know how to get the Class of that object using something like this:

```
private String getCallerClassName() {
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 1; i < stElements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
        if (!ste.getClassName().equals(B.class.getName()) && ste.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread") != 0)
            return ste.getClassName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

which I got from a different question: [How to get the caller class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306811/how-to-get-the-caller-class-in-java).
Is there a way to get a pointer to the caller object?

Comment: Sorry, Java doesn't work that way.  If you want a back reference to `A` in `B`, you need to create one yourself.

Comment: `b.somethingElse(this);`

Comment: If you can't change method signatures or pass reference of `A` to `B` then you can use ThreadLocal where you can put `A` into the ThreadLocal before calling `b.somethingElse();` and get it from ThreadLocal inside `somethingElse` method. You can further automate this using AOP.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the source code, and if `B` can only be created by an `A` object, you could make `B` a non-static inner class, and then you would automatically get a reference back to the creator of the class, through the `A.this` pointer. Note this isn't the caller of `B::somethingElse()`, but the creator of `B`, which may or may not be the same thing, depending on your use case.

```
public class A {
    public B obj = new B();

    public void something() {
        obj.somethingElse();
    }

    void thereAndBackAgain() {
    }

    public class B {

        public void somethingElse() {
            A owner = A.this; 
            owner.thereAndBackAgain(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without nested classes and not changing A?

Comment: Without nested classes?  Sure.  Without changing `A` at all?  Probably not.  You’d at least have pass `this` to either B’s constructor `new B(this)` or the call `obj.somethingElse(this)`, both of which is changing `class A { ... }` code.  Otherwise you have no guarantee that the “owner”/“caller” is even an object of type `A`; some class `Q` could create your public `B` and invoke the public `somethingElse` method.

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped a lot