# How to know which methods are invoked in java?

Tags: java, methods, runtime

Is there any way to know which methods are getting invoked in Java during run time. Actually I am trying to detect those methods which are getting invoked and according to those methods that are invoked use Java Reflection APIS to invoke another method from another classes. In this way I want to divert the execution to my methods first and then call those running methods.

e.g

```
//Method Invoked_Method = "get the invoked method here "

   if(Invoked_Method.equals("somemethodName"){
   //invoke Another method ..
   }
```

Although its a security breach, but I am working in team for security products. So have to experiment this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find method name from within that method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641540/how-to-find-method-name-from-within-that-method-in-java)

Comment: [Thread.getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace())

Comment: @JigarJoshi this looks like a monitor that will run on a different thread`. Probably OP could use [`Thread#getAllStackTraces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29) but this still doesn't look like a good option.

Comment: @JigarJoshi : Yes. I am looking to get the run on different thread. Well Let me try the method 1 in first comment. Thanks for help !!

Comment: @jigarJoshi: this is not the duplicate question, well I am trying something like method interception here. But thanks for your reply http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes StackTrace is not a good option. Aspect Oriented Programming is better solution to it.Thanks for the help . http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider AOP: http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/

This allows you to intercept method calls that match a particular expression and enhance or change the default behaviour of the method.

If you're already using them, the Spring and Guice frameworks provide ways to leverage AOP relatively easily.

Comment: So happy for this reply. Seems like found answers for all my questions. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are saying is you need to trace the callstack at runtime. I found a thread regarding this. 
[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706292/java-determining-current-call-stack-for-diagnostic-purposes)