# Hiding System.out.print calls of a class

Tags: java

I'm using a java library (jar file). The author of the file put in a bunch of `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`s. Is there any way to hide these messages for a particular object?

*EDIT: It looks like the jar file seems to be creating a bunch of threads and each thread has it's own System.out.println's...

Answer (score 43):

Change original **PrintStream** with a **Dummy** one which does nothing on it's `write()` method.

Don't forget to replace original **PrintStream** when you finished.

```
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN SEE ME");

PrintStream originalStream = System.out;

PrintStream dummyStream = new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
    public void write(int b) {
        // NO-OP
    }
});

System.setOut(dummyStream);
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN NOT");

System.setOut(originalStream);
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN SEE ME AGAIN");
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but won't this hide all system.outs? i want to keep the ones that i have in my program but hide the ones that the jar created.

Comment: Just before a method from jar invoked use `System.setOut(dummyStream);`. Just after a method from jar invoked use `System.setOut(originalStream);`. Ok?

Comment: Not exactly. The jar file creates a bunch of threads that each do a System.out...

Comment: @K2xL in that case use **`dummyStream`** all the time. When you need to print something to console use **`originalStream`**.

Answer (score 7):

`System.setOut();` is probably what you're looking for

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
  public void write(int b) {
    // NO-OP
  }
}));
```

[Source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/172772)

Comment: Note: This will stop the `System.out.println` and `System.out.print` calls from *all* classes.

Comment: ah yes i just asked the author of the above answer this question... so there's no way to hide it from just one specific file? i have some system.outs in my class that i don't want to hide... just the ones the author of this jar has..

Comment: @K2xL what do you mean by **just one specific file**? Please show us the problematic part of your code.

Comment: For hiding from one specific class file or multiple class files you could aspect. Aspectj with above would work great!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways I can think of doing this other than what has been previously posted:
1. Use a Java decompiler and remove each `System.out` call and recompile the jar. I would reccommend [this one](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) if you choose this route.
2. You can use the stack trace to find the calling type. (From [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421280/758280))

```
List<String> classNames = ...
final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
PrintStream filterStream = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
         StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
         if(!classNames.contains(stackTraceElements[someNumber].getClassName()){
              originalOut.write(b);
         }
    }
});
System.setOut(filterStream);
```

Where `classNames` is the fully qualified name of every class in the jar file and `someNumber` is the correct place in the stack you need to be looking at (probably 1 or 2).

/e1
After some testing I believe the number you will need for `someNumber` is either 10 or 11. This is because `System.out.print` does not directly call the `write` method.

Example stack trace for writing `h`:

(Stack traces are in index, `getClassName`, `getFileName`, `getMethodName` order).

```
0   java.lang.Thread    null    getStackTrace
1   reflection.StackTrace$1 StackTrace.java write
2   java.io.OutputStream    null    write
3   java.io.PrintStream null    write
4   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    writeBytes
5   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    implFlushBuffer
6   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    flushBuffer
7   java.io.OutputStreamWriter  null    flushBuffer
8   java.io.PrintStream null    write
9   java.io.PrintStream null    print
10  java.io.PrintStream null    println
11  reflection.StackTrace   StackTrace.java main
```

Example stack trace for writing `\n`:

```
0   java.lang.Thread    null    getStackTrace
1   reflection.StackTrace$1 StackTrace.java write
2   java.io.OutputStream    null    write
3   java.io.PrintStream null    write
4   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    writeBytes
5   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    implFlushBuffer
6   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder    null    flushBuffer
7   java.io.OutputStreamWriter  null    flushBuffer
8   java.io.PrintStream null    newLine
9   java.io.PrintStream null    println
10  reflection.StackTrace   StackTrace.java main
```

`reflection.StackTrace` is the main class I'm using to do the test. `reflection.StackTrace$1` is my `filterStream` and I'm calling `System.out.println` from the `main` method in `reflection.StackTrace`.

/e2
This 11 or 10 discrepancy appears to be because `println` calls `print` and `newLine`. `print` goes on to call `write` while `newLine` directly writes the new line character to the stream. But this shouldn't matter since the jar will not contain `java.io.PrintStream`.

Comment: interesting solution... it seems overly complicated but i guess it might be the only solution...

Answer (score 1):

Solution of your question is [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455675/7346931) in method `SysOutController.ignoreSysout();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bigger programm consider something like

```
public abstract class Output {
    private static final PrintStream out = System.out;
    private static final PrintStream dummy = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {@Override public void write(int b){} });

    private static boolean globalOutputOn = true;
    public static void toggleOutput() {
        System.setOut((globalOutputOn=!globalOutputOn)?dummy:out);
    }

    public static void toggleOutput(boolean on) {
        globalOutputOn = on;
        System.setOut(on?out:dummy);
    }
}
```

This gurantees that you can toggle output on and off in different classes, while beeing guranteed to be able to turn the output on later.

You for example use it by calling

`toggleOutput(false)` at the start of each method and

`toggleOutput(true)` at the end of each method.