# Use Maven Library without Drinking Maven Koolaid

Tags: java, maven

I want to use the diffplug/Durian library, but do not want to use Maven. Is there a way to use a Maven library without using Maven itself in a project?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can go to the [maven central repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and download the jar you want without using maven.

Comment: The maven central repo seems like what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem to be the universe of Maven projects. The library I needed, Durian from diffplug, is not in that list, for example.

Comment: I think it's check this folder: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/diffplug/durian/ . If you don't know the groupid/artefact, you can search for them in http://search.maven.org. By the way, maven is awesome :D

Comment: Aha, of course! Thanks for showing me that.

Answer (score 1):

I found that IntelliJ IDEA allows for exporting of a Maven module to a JAR, that can be used in non-Maven projects.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html

And needed to know what a "Maven Coordinate" was. I found it for the library in question at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.diffplug.durian/durian/3.4.0, and it is the string "com.diffplug.durian:durian:3.4.0".

Basically, follow Project Structure->Project Settings->Libraries->"+"->New Project Library->From Maven. The resultant dialog takes a Maven coordinate, and has a "Download To" option, that will make a nice JAR at the specified location, from the Maven library you import. Can add source and javadocs as well. After doing the download, you navigate to the system folder containing the new JAR, and stick it in your real non-Maven project (an Eclipse project, in my case).

Answer (score 1):

This has a link to the .jar and lists it's dependencies. 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.diffplug.durian/durian/3.4.0

Download the jar - then all the jar's dependencies and their dependencies and add them to the class path.

Comment: For a library with few dependencies, this is acceptable and easier than using IntelliJ IDEA, if one does not have it installed already. Augusto also showed me how to find the jar in the maven global repo. For cases with more dependencies, one has to do a lot more clicking, and dependency versioning may make it frustrating.

Comment: Hence the maven Koolaid - maven is quite easy to use - I'm genuinely curious why you avoid it.

Comment: You got it :) There are only two good reason currently: I haven't got enough lively dependencies to warrant it, and it increases on-boarding cost. Also, it's an application where security is irrelevant. Besides, just as with toilet paper roll orientation, I have a difference of preference. If I had to use Maven or thought it would help, I would try it.