# Turn off Java-Console Output for the next X lines?

Tags: java, console, system.out

I would like to know if it is possible in Java to hide all Console-Print-Outs for a certain amount of lines or time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Java console output" is actually written to [java.System.out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

If you wanted to "stop output" for some period, you could could temporarily "redirect" System.out to a dummy stream; some stream that doesn't write anything.

Look here: [Hiding System.out.print calls of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363493/hiding-system-out-print-calls-of-a-class)

```
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN SEE ME");

PrintStream originalStream = System.out;

PrintStream dummyStream = new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
    public void write(int b) {
        // NO-OP
    }
});

System.setOut(dummyStream);
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN NOT");

System.setOut(originalStream);
System.out.println("NOW YOU CAN SEE ME AGAIN");
```

Comment: Why did you just link the question itself again?

Comment: @Li357 - whoops! Thank you for pointing out that I copied/pasted the wrong URL.  I updated the post with the correct one - and also included the example code.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great!  Thank you for following up!