# Finding classpath of class invoking a library

Tags: java, classloader, reflections

I am using google [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) in a java library I am developing.
The reason I use Reflections is because I want to find all the classes with a particular annotation.
Simplifying things, in my library I have a method answering those classes, that is invoked with a line like:

```
//this method uses the Reflections library
Repository.getDefault().getMyAnnotatedClasses()
```

In the current version of my library, I require the user to explicitly add the package name where the Reflections library need to look for the annotated classes:

```
Repository.getDefault().addSearchPath("...");
```

In this way Reflections will look for classes located only in that package.

If the user of my library does not add this search path, I configure Reflections to search in all the classes in the system class loader. Obviously this solution is quite inefficient. However, I really want to get rid of the requirement of asking the user to ALWAYS set the search path. 
- A side note in case it is important: in Reflections you can configure a search path with a package name, a url (the classpath where the classes can be found), or a class loader.

So my question is: Is there a way to find the classpath of the class invoking my library ? (from my library code). 
In this way, I could detect that if the user has not explicitly set a search location, I will add that location by default, which seems to be a better solution than adding the entire system class loader as the alternative search path.

I know I could manually inspect the method call stack from my library code, but this seems a bit of a hack and dirty solution, so I am looking for alternative ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the caller of a method by analyzing the stacktrace. Although not a good idea in general IMHO as it breaks encapsulation and sensitive to managed environments (proxies and so), it will work. Look more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection).

What else you can do, and **avoid the inefficiency** of scanning all classpath every time, is to scan and save once on compile time with reflections, and than collect it on bootstrap time.

To scan and save once as XML:

```
new Reflections(...).save([somepath]);
```

And than collect without scanning:

```
Reflections reflections = Reflections.collect([somepath]);
```

If you're using Maven, you can automate it and do it as part of every build using the Reflections-Maven plugin.

Look for more info at **collect pre scanned metadata** in the Reflections [UseCases Wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/UseCases)