# Getting the caller class in the Google's EventBus

Tags: events, guava

I  have a listening method that waits for a `FooBarEvent` in the `Dummy` class:

```
@Subscribe
public void testingEvents(FooBarEvent event) {

}
```

On the other hand, I have a class that needs that method :

```
public class TestEvents{
    public TestEvents(event){
        FooBarEvent event = new FooBarEvent (...);
        event.post(event);
    }
}
```

This is called from the main class which acts like this :

```
EventBus bus = new EventBus();
bus.register(new Dummy());
```

The question is : How can get, at the `testingEvents`(the subscriber), the class that posted the events?.

(As a result, I'm expecting to get at that method that the caller is the `TestEvents` class).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In most code I've seen, it's the events themselves that have a `source` field indicating where the event originated.  Can you just add a field to `FooBarEvent` that either contains the source object (or just the class of the source, if it's all you need)?

Comment: Your answer is clearly correct. But, I wonder if the `EventBus` has an out-of-the-box mechanism that would allow to get the event's source.

Comment: (Indeed, how would you _possibly_ implement such a feature?)

Comment: (You could access it using reflection but that would be ugly and slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection )