# How to determine which class is sending message via System.out

Tags: java

I have an application which redirect `System.out` for example;

```
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out){
    @Override
    public void print(String string)
    {
      //TODO: find out who sent the print before processing string
    }
  });
```

I want to be able to determine which class is sending the call to print to stdout? I think this is not possible, but cannot fully conclude unless `SO` say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent version of HotSpot or OpenJDK you can use `Reflection.getCallerClass(2 or 3)` This is more efficient than generating a full stack trace but not portable.

Otherwise, the most efficient way to get the stack trace is

```
StackTraceElement[] stes = Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace();
```

This avoid creating an Exception or Throwable.

Answer (score 2):

Get the [stacktrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) and find the class name from the currect index.

```
StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Comment: In this case it is not particularly easy to determine the correct index in the stack trace and `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` is probably better than `new Exception().getStackTrace()`.

Comment: @jarnbjo: +1. one stack down the trace.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception, and examine the stack trace. Obviously not great for production code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways: SecurityManager might be the best. Check this post especially the second answer: [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)