# How can i know the name of class who is calling my class ? i need not want the callee to provide any information abut its class

Tags: java

I need  an suggestion  on this

```
 class A{
    B b;
 }

 Class B{
    P String  something();
 }
```

In

```
 class test{
    B b = new B();
    b.something();
 }

something()
```

must  return the name of the cal-lee class
its like  if somebody calls me(by name) I should know his name.

Comment: You want to get "A" or "B" here ?

Comment: please check below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection

Hope it helps to you

Comment: If you need to know who is calling you, you most likely have a design/architectural issue.

Answer (score 6):

A solution is to programmatically generate a stack trace:

```
private static String getCallerName() {
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i=1; i<stElements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement ste = stElements[i];
        if (!ste.getClassName().equals("B") && ste.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread")!=0) {
            return ste.getClassName();
            // you could also use ste.getMethodName() or ste.getLineNumber()
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You would use it like this, for example :

```
public void something() {
   System.out.println("called by " + getCallerName());
}
```

Comment: May i know where all have you used this? (stand alone, distributed)

Comment: +1, I did a if(true){try{throw new NullpointerException()}catch(Exception ex){ and here I had the stack trace }} :)

Comment: @aksappy I'm not sure I get your comment. I use a similar thing in some debug tools.

Comment: Is there any alternate method to do instead of StackTraceElement[] ?

Comment: @user2143318 Why ? This makes only sense when logging or debugging. What's the problem you have with the stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody calls you by name, you wouldn't know it, unless that somebody already told it to you.

Same thing here.

Pass your name from class A to class B.

Comment: ya ,i should not know it.But my requirement is to know the person calling me.Thanks for giving a different look to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem seems a bit extraordinary, an architectural alternative. Whether it fits better I do not know.

```
class A {
    class C extends B {
        String something() {
            ... A.this
        }
    }
}
```