# How can my method, which is being called by another class, obtain a variable from that class without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: java, methods, static, field, getter

A method in BayesianClassifier calls the method below (a method of Category):

```
public void updateProbabilities(Map<String, int> woordfrequenties) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, int> woordfrequentie : woordfrequenties.entrySet()) {
        String woord = woordfrequentie.getKey();
        int frequentie = woordfrequentie.getValue();
        int index = BayesianClassifier.getVocabulary().indexOf(woord);
    }
}
```

Now, it states that the non-static method getVocabulary from BayesianClassifier cannot be referenced from the static context here, which I understand, but how then can the method get the value of field 'vocabulary' from the instance of BayesianClassifier that calls this method? It surely must be possible without passing the whole vocabulary as a parameter, or giving the class Category the instance of BayesianClassifier as a field?

Comment: What if an object of some other class called your method?  How would you know how to obtain the desired index?

Comment: What is wrong with just passing `vocabulary` as a parameter? It's not that long, and causes no issues. Technically, though, you can analyse the stack trace using Reflection (generally, DO NOT DO THIS, however). See an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329566/how-to-find-the-object-that-called-a-method-in-java

Comment: Generally speaking, a method -- particularly a public method -- knows nothing about who invoked it.  It has only its arguments and the object on which it was invoked to work with.  And this is good.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I will just give the class Category a field containing the calling class BayesianClassifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments it can be done with Reflection. If you **cannot** pass vocabulary as a parameter then go with the answer here: [Previous Answer to Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329566/how-to-find-the-object-that-called-a-method-in-java/)

If you do not want to use Reflection you have two options:

**Option 1:**

Just pass in the Vocabulary object when calling `updateProbabilities`. Java is *pass-by-value*, however this does not mean that the entire Vocabulary object will be copied and passed. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). Essentially, the value of the pointer to your object will be passed, and in doing so only take up the extra space of one "pointer".

**Option 2:**

When creating your `Category` object, add the `BayesianClassifier` as a field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's using following code:

```
public class Category {
private final BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier;

public Category(BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier) {
  this.bayesianClassifier = bayesianClassifier;
}

public void updateProbabilities(Map<String, int> woordfrequenties) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, int> woordfrequentie : woordfrequenties.entrySet()) {
        String woord = woordfrequentie.getKey();
        int frequentie = woordfrequentie.getValue();
        int index = bayesianClassifier.getVocabulary().indexOf(woord);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Category {
private BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier;

public void setBayesianClassifier(BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier) {
  this.bayesianClassifier = bayesianClassifier;
}

public void updateProbabilities(Map<String, int> woordfrequenties, BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, int> woordfrequentie : woordfrequenties.entrySet()) {
        String woord = woordfrequentie.getKey();
        int frequentie = woordfrequentie.getValue();
        int index = bayesianClassifier.getVocabulary().indexOf(woord);
    }
}
```

or

```
public void updateProbabilities(Map<String, int> woordfrequenties, BayesianClassifier bayesianClassifier) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, int> woordfrequentie : woordfrequenties.entrySet()) {
            String woord = woordfrequentie.getKey();
            int frequentie = woordfrequentie.getValue();
            int index = bayesianClassifier.getVocabulary().indexOf(woord);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I will use this, thank you! I just wanted to check if there was a way of doing this without adding an instance of BayesianClassifier as a field to Category. Thanks again!