# Get object who called current object

Tags: java

I have a class Player, with a an object player_1, and an another class Weapon.
From my object player_1 i call a method who is located in class Weapon `player_1.getWeapon().changeDurability(int x)`

```
void changeDurability( int x) {
// changing durability
// and then i want to do something like this :
if( durability <= 0) player1.setWeaponBroken(true)
}
```

But i don't know how to get the player1 from the Weapon object,
and is there a way to do this instead of changing the method to something like this: 
`void changeDurability(Player player, int x)`

Thanks in advance for any helping answers.

Comment: It is not advisable to get the object who called your method, see other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329566/how-to-find-the-object-that-called-a-method-in-java or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072542/can-i-get-the-instance-of-the-calling-object-in-java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix your call to the player's weapon - without fixing Weapon class:

```
// Player code
public void changeWeaponDurability(int x) {
    player_1.getWeapon().changeDurability(x);
    if (player_1.getWeapon().getDurability() <= 0) {
        player_1.setWeaponBroken(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a weapon is broken is information that belongs to that weapon, not to the player using it.  I would recommend that you move the `isBroken` variable to the `Weapon` class and then have a method like this in your `Player` class:

```java
boolean isWeaponBroken(){
    return this.getWeapon().isBroken
}
```