# How to recognize calling object?

Tags: java

Can I recognize my calling object? 
I can create *stacktrace* for *classname* of `A` but how can I access an object of `A`?

```
class A{
    void method(){
        new B().method();
    }
}

class B{
    void method(){
        // can i recognize Object A ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that! It's not a good idea to produce that kind of tight coupling. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: i know, i know.. but sometimes - do you know a way to find Object of A?

Comment: Sometimes what? The only 2 parts that I could reasonably think of requiring that information are security checks (see `SecurityManager`, that's already done) and possibly logging (see your favorite logging framework, also already done).

Comment: Can you not pass B as a method parameter into B::method(A a). Not that this is usually wise

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`StrackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

The top element is what you are looking for.

Also go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection).

Comment: Why do you link to some third-party site that just replicates what's already [in the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)? Especially since your answer already links to the JavaDoc itself.

Comment: Just because of that small summary of methods in a tabular form. Provided the reference as a source so it is not plagiarism

Comment: That's *exactly* the same information that's provided here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#method_summary. So there's no need to refer to a third-party site at all (plus: posting textual information as an image is bad for searchability, accessibility and copy-and-pasting).

Comment: i look for calling object and not only for calling class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection

Comment: @FrankM.: that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

javadoc:

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack,
>   which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

and the documentation of what you can get from each StackTraceElement

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

```
getClassName()
getFileName()
getLineNumber() 
getMethodName()
```

Comment: i look for calling object and not only for calling class.

Answer (score 1):

If you really *need* to do this, then you should incorporate it into the code.

```
class A{
    void method(){
        new B().method(this);
    }
}

class B{
    void method(A a){
        System.out.println("I recognize 'a' as " + A);
    }
}
```