# sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass alternative

Tags: java, stack-trace

From [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)  ( as I didn't have enough reputation to comment there itself )

Since sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass has been removed in jdk8,
What could be an alternative ?

How about using 
sun.misc.SharedSecrets

```
    JavaLangAccess access = SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess();
    Throwable throwable = new Throwable();
    int depth = access.getStackTraceDepth(throwable);
    StackTraceElement frame = access.getStackTraceElement(throwable, depth);
```

Comment: Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace() (note that it will return `Thread.getStackTrace` and the current method as the first 2 stack elements)

Comment: Invoking that will cause the entire stack trace to be created, very inefficient. I just want access to the frame at certain depth. Actually, the alternative which I suggested, probably that will also create the full stack trace. I am not sure.

Comment: I would say avoid using `sun.*` packages because they won't be there on all platforms and java configurations. Also, why would getting the entire stack trace be inefficient? Do you have a lot of things in the stack, or do you need this at a high rate? Don't worry about efficiency unless it actually makes a difference

Comment: I use it somewhere in my code for debugging purpose. In long term, I will remove it, but for now I might have to resort to the method explained above.

Comment: @ZoveGames could you add your answer as an actual Answer instead of just a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above. I came to the conclusion to use  `SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess()` as explained above in short term, but remove the dependency on `sun.*` package entirely as a long term solution.

Basically I am changing my requirement itself so that it does not require `getCallerClass` functionality.

Answer (score 4):

I hava code

```
String callerClass = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass().getName()
```

in my project ,while I changed my jdk to 1.8 ,the code throws Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: CallerSensitive annotation expected at frame 1
```

There are two ways to replace `Reflection.getCallerClass()`

```
 StackTraceElement[] elements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
    String  callerClass = elements[1].getClassName();
```

or

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
    String  callerClass = elements[1].getClassName();
```

good luck