# WARNING: "sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance"

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, libgdx, pi4j

I receive this warning message in the output of my videogame. The game was tested on Raspberry Pi 3 with 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS and Raspberry Pi 4b with 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS.
The game uses Java 11 and root privileges. The game was created using LibGDX framework and Pi4j library. What is that and how can this message affect the performance?

Comment: Performance should be the least concerning aspect of a game with root privileges.

Comment: A library that insists on using a hack like that probably isn’t a good library.

Answer (score 2):

Based purely on the message and some trivial googling - it means

1. a programmer wants to call getCallerClass
2. it has been determined that it's not possible- since that call was removed in Java 8
3. the program that wanted to use it is telling you, uselessly, that it may underperform

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808803/sun-reflect-reflection-getcallerclass-alternative).