# How can I verify that the second static method was invoked in the first static method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

How can I verify that the second static method was invoked within the first static method using the PowerMock framework?

```
public class A {
    public static int firstMethod(String s) {
        return secondMethod(s, 10);
    }

    public static int secondMethod(String s, Integer i){
        return /*some expression*/;
    }
}
```

*Update:*

I haven't see yet any solution using the PowerMock framework. And definitely there are no acceptable answers for me in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection).

*Update2:*

```
@Test
public void test() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    Mockito.when(A.secondMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(1000);
    A.firstMethod("test");
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you mock/monitor the second static method the same way you'd do if you were only checking the first?

Comment: mock the second method, invoke the first one and then verify...

Comment: But how can I be sure that verification is verifying the second static method? I added code to the question.

Comment: what's wrong with `assertEquals(1000, A.firstMethod("test"))`; ?

Comment: Nothing. But if I need to check invocation of method, not integer result. In this case I need to check the invocation process of the second method.

Comment: This assertion ensure that the method is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bad design.  You shouldn't HAVE to check internal details such as which methods are called.

But having said that, why not just make sure your first method returns the correct answer when the second method is mocked?

```
@Test
public void test() {
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
   Mockito.when(A.secondMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(1000);
   //1000 was returned by your mocked method
   assertEquals(1000, A.firstMethod("test") );
   PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
}
```

This assumes your code example is valid for your question where `firstMethod` delegates and returns the call from `secondMethod`