# Same function, different jobs

Tags: java, function, oop

This is more of a design question. How do I make a function perform different tasks depending on where is it being called from. For example

```
public doSomething(int a, int b) {
a=a+b; //line 1
b=a+b; //line 2
}
```

Now how do I make either line 1 or line 2 to execute depending of where the function doSomething is being called from. I would prefer not to pass any extra variables to the function, as this function is being used in a lot of places and it would mess up my existing code

Comment: "where the function doSomething is being called from" you mean class??

Comment: yeah its a public function and is being called from two different functions of the same class.

Comment: This is more of a design answer: change your design. You might think your proposal will be an easy fix, but it promises to become a maintenance nightmare very soon. [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you really, *really* need it, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/421338/240443) describes what you need to do - but it is slow and I can't tell you enough how much I recommend against doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really make your method behave according to the context without

1. Pass a parameter with context information to the method.
2. Have the Class containing the method have a context object with the necessary information.
3. Get the caller context information from somewhere like a cache etc.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a function should do one thing and do it well.

It's conceivable that the one thing should be one of a selection but only if there's a lot of commonality.

The best way to do that is exactly the way you seem reticent to use, you pass more information on what to do.

Perhaps the problem we *should* be solving is your reticence or the proposed design :-)

---

If there is commonality and you're not willing to change the API because of the effect on current callers, there is another way.

Provide a *new* function to the new specification and change the old function to call it. For example, say you have a function to find the sum of two numbers:

```
def sum (a, b):
    return a + b
```

Now you want a new function that will either give you the sum or the difference and you don't want to change the current callers:

```
def sumOrDiff (type, a, b):
    if type == 'sum':
        return a + b
    return abs (a - b)

def sum (a, b):
    return sumOrDiff ('sum', a, b);
```

That way, you have the common code in one place (and I'd hope it's more complex than that) but without changing the calls already using it.

This is a well-worn method for making changes while keeping code simple, and not breaking backward compatibility.

Now that's a contrived example. In reality, I'd *still* provide a separate function for sum and difference. Your *actual* use case will hopefully make more sense.

Comment: haha actually my boss doesn't like when I do that, i.e. passing a boolean value which tells the function what to do.

Comment: And another reason is that that function is being used my numerous other modules, which I am not developing. So it will be headache for those programmers. I guess I will have to create a second function.

Comment: @Ritwick, for once the boss may be right :-) Only do the boolean thing if the two actions have a lot in common. Otherwise, create a separate function.

Comment: They do have a lot in common, everything but 1 line actually. The main issue is other developers are using that function too, and it will create ambiguity with them

Answer (score 1):

You could use this.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); 


 for(StackTraceElement st : stackTrace){ // check st for further processing}
```

This will give you the stack trace. Depending upon the depth of your function call. You can check and have your condition accordingly.

Note: this has performance issue. I would recommend changing your design or use a boolean parameter in your function which decides the further flow.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Same as Amadan's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question - one approach might be adding a field like `count` to your class,

```
private int count = 0;
public doSomething(int a, int b) {
  if (count == 0) {
    a=a+b; //line 1
  } else {
    b=a+b; //line 2
  }
  count++;
}
```

Obviously this only works directly when called `line 1` then `line 2`. However, you could add something like

```
public void reset() {
  count = 0;
}
```

Of course this is just gluing context into your class - and it's probably easier to add a 3rd parameter overloaded method for "line 2" -

```
public void doSomething(int a, int b) {
  doSomething(a, b, 0);
}

public void doSomething(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (c == 0) {
    a=a+b; //line 1
  } else {
    b=a+b; //line 2
  }
}
```

And then you only have to change line 2 methods.