# How do you determine the data type of calling object in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

When I'm calling a function in Groovy, how do I determine the class of the caller?

For example, I want to know what the class of `foo` is, inside the `printFoo()` function:

```
foo.printFoo()

def printFoo() {
  print(this.class)
}
```

And this should print out the class of `foo`

Comment: Not sure about Groovy specific, but Java provides a way which is specified in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

Comment: `this.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: @christopher That technique is going to be problematic, particularly with Groovy's dynamic dispatch because there are going to be potentially a lot of frames between the caller and the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language and the runtime don't provide a reliable mechanism to do what you are asking about.  You can do some pokey jiggery inspecting stack frames but that is really detailed low level stuff and won't really be reliable for a number of reasons.  The short answer is, the language just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any Groovy-specific way, but you can get the class name with `object.getClass().name`. Is that what you are looking for?

If you want to check if an object implements a particular interface or extends a particular class (e.g. Date) use:

```
object instanceof Date
```

or to check if the class of an object is exactly a particular class (not a subclass of it), use:

```
object.getClass() == Date
```

There's also the `in` operator: `object in Date`

Comment: My question is more related to the class of the object that called the function, so if foo calls printFoo(), how would you access the foo's class, inside printFoo()?

Comment: Then your example should work. What's the error or problem with it?

Comment: Ah, okay. I wasn't sure if it was proper syntax/form. Thanks!

Comment: You should call `getClass()` instead of `class`.