# Find potential methods that invoke a method using reflection or static code analysis

Tags: java, reflection, static-analysis

This question is not a duplicate of - [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

I am trying to analyze *all possible paths* to a particular method for my codebase. I'm envisioning something like this:

```
Class clazz = MyClass.class;
Method method = clazz.getMethod("myMethod");
Method[] possibleCallers = getMethodsThatInvokeMethod(method); // <-- How do I implement this
```

Is this possible using reflection? If not, are there any open libraries that can help?

UPDATE: For clarification, I would only like to find the possible *static* invocations of a given method in the project.

Comment: Not quite clear: do you want to analyze source code or byte code?

Comment: @Andremoniy , I would be happy with either source code or byte code analysis as long as either approach was able to provide a complete list of potential caller methods. Does that help?