# How can I find the class/package/instance that creates object of my class?

Tags: java

I am implementing a class that is supposed to have a instance in many different parts of a bigger project. How can I find out at runtime where an object of my class was created? For example in which class or in which package.

Comment: A debugger or a profiler would probably help.

Comment: Can u explain the reason why you do want to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the stack of the call than access the single StackTraceElement as needed:

```
public YourConstructor() {
     ....
     StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
     int depth = 1;   // Check for different depths is necessary.
     System.out.println(stackTraceElements[depth].getClassName());
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Java's stacktrace element.

Check here for that and more alternatives [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)