# Java: determine if a static method is called from an instance or statically

Tags: java, reflection, static, instance, static-methods

In Java, is it possible to determine whether a static method is called from either an instance of the object, or statically (`SomeClass.method()`)?

To give you an a better idea of what I'm talking about, take look at this code below:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void staticMethod() {

        if (/*called from instance*/) {
            System.out.println("Called from an instance.");
        } else if (/*called statically*/){
            System.out.println("Called statically.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass().staticMethod();//prints "Called from an instance."
        SomeClass.staticMethod();//prints "Called statically."
    }

}
```

I understand it isn't good practice to call a static method from an instance, but still, is it possible to differentiate between these two calls? I was thinking that the Reflection API probably holds the key to this.

Comment: Why not SomeClass.staticMethod(someclassObj)?

Comment: Thats not possible, it compiles to exactly the same bytecode.

Comment: No.  As far as I know, the two calls compile to exactly the same bytecode.  (And @tkausl wins by 14 seconds)

Comment: This question makes me cringe.

Comment: You should really ask yourself why you think you need that (and if there is not a better way to achieve whatever the real task is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible by just calling the method. However you can gain some useful information from the stacktrace explained here [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

This will allow you to determine the method name and/or caller class using the static method

Comment: Not really an answer.

Comment: ok. editted to directly say its not possible which is an answer.

Comment: In the example, the caller class/method name would be identical for both cases, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think reflection can make this. But, you can make it in another way:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void staticMethod(boolean isStaticCall) {

        if (!isStaticCall) {
            System.out.println("Called from an instance.");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Called statically.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass().staticMethod(false);//prints "Called from an instance."
        SomeClass.staticMethod(true);//prints "Called statically."
    }

}
```

Comment: The caller could lie about it, though.

Comment: Absolutely! Anyway,  java program will never be strong enough. Eg: private inner class.