# Can you add a function object to a map in Java?

Tags: java, function

Say I have a small demo to count the number of times a method is called, e.g.

```
public class Test {

    public static Map<Function<String, Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Test() {
        map.put(this::method1, 0);
        map.put(this::method2, 0);
    }

    public Integer method1(String a) {
        Integer time = map.get(this::method1);
        map.put(this::method1, time + 1);
        return time;
    }

    public Integer method2(String a) {
        Integer time = map.get(this::method2);
        map.put(this::method2, time + 1);
        return time;
    }
}
```

The code above demoed the idea, but the code doesn't compile. It does not complain at the `map.put()`; it complains at the `map.get()` parts. Do you have an explanation? As well as a way to fix this (while still using function objects and a map, not two individual integers to do the counting).

Comment: What's the parameter type of `Map#get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@SotiriosDelimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477199/can-you-add-function-object-to-map-in-java#comment72094845_42477199) hinted, [`Map.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) accepts `Object`, not the key type, so the compiler is unable to infer the target lambda type. There are a few possible workarounds.

1. Create a temporary variable:

   ```
   Function<String, Integer> key = this::method1;
   Integer time = map.get(key);
   ```
2. Cast the lambda to the target type:

   ```
   Integer time = map.get((Function<String, Integer>)this::method1);
   ```
3. Use an overload that does accept the key type, like [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). This also improves your code by merging the get and put into one statement, and possibly making the constructor initialization unnecessary (did you really mean to initialize to 1?):

   ```
   map.merge(this::method1, 1, Integer::sum);
   ```

Comment: Haha, no, it was a typo. But yeah, good information there you provided. But sadly the function objects was not the same and the map could not look them up...

Comment: @user1589188 You could cache the method references outside the method instead of recreating them inside. But it's probably even simpler to just use a string or enum key, since there's nothing really tying the method reference to the executing method (that would only be possible by [digging though the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/421280/1553851)).

Answer (score 4):

You can make this compile by casting the function in the get method:

```
map.get((Function<String, Integer>)this::method2);
```

But the code still won't work.

Each lambda expression creates a new function class, and since `Function` does not implement hashcode and equals, the only way you could use them as map keys is if you use the same instance/object for the insertion and lookup.
That said, I can't think of a reason why you would ever want to use a function as a map key.

Comment: Yes you are right, got it compiled but can't lookup the methods...to bad.