# How to diffrenciate callback function when several objects call it

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

I have a class which connects to a web service and then returns the response. The class is working in a different thread. It is called **SoapConnector**. There is an interface which notify the caller that the response is ready. It is:

```
public interface ISoapConnectorObserver {
    public void onSoapRequestFinished(String response);
```

}

When the response is ready, the **onSoapRequestFinished()** is called.

I use the SoapConnector for fetching different data. For example CustomerReader for reading the customers from server and ProductReader for reading the products list. How can i change the *ISoapConnectorObserver* to **differentiate** the return value from **CustomerReader** or **ProductReader**?

```
public class CustomerReader {
    private observer ISoapConnectorObserver observer;

    public CustomerReader(ISoapConnectorObserver observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }
    .
    .
}

public class ProductReader {
    private observer ISoapConnectorObserver observer;

    public ProductReader(ISoapConnectorObserver observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

I want to find an elegant way to not to use another helper class, but extending this interface or changing the onSoapRequestFinished(). Thanks

Comment: You either should only notify the source of the request or include a source parameter like `public void onSoapRequestFinished(object source, String response);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

Comment: @Fildor can you please write a sample?

Comment: @ehsantoghian Do you have a link to the API or method? The answer may lie in the parameter passed into the `onSoapRequestFinished()`. Maybe it contains the function that called it.

Comment: Actually no. Without having the SoapConnector code, that's pretty impossible. Whatever you do, you'll have to keep track of origin of request.