# Calling class name for a generic logger

Tags: scala, generics, logging

I am trying to make a generic Logger for a project, but I am unable of getting the name of the calling class in the log traces.

I have tried to get the name of the calling class using super.getClass, but it doesn't seem to work the way I'd like to.
Right now, this is where I am at:

```
object GeneralLogger {

    val newLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(super.getClass)
    val configFile: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

    def SparkLogger(event: ErrorEvent) : Unit = {

      val sparkAppName: String = configFile.getString("spark.appName")
      val sparkMaster: String = configFile.getString("spark.master")
      val sparkCrossJoin: String = configFile.getString("spark.crossJoin")
      val sparkSqlWarehouse: String = configFile.getString("spark.sqlWarehouse")
      val sparkExecutorMemory: String = configFile.getString("spark.sparkExecutorMemory")

      newLogger.info("--- Spark Parameters ---")
      newLogger.info("sparkAppName: " + sparkAppName.toString)
      newLogger.info("sparkMaster: " + sparkMaster.toString)
      newLogger.info("sparkCrossJoin: " + sparkCrossJoin.toString)
      newLogger.info("sparkSqlWarehouse: " + sparkSqlWarehouse.toString)
      newLogger.info("sparkExecutorMemory: " + sparkExecutorMemory.toString)

    }

    def CassandraLogger() : Unit = {

      val cassandraHost: util.List[String] = configFile.getStringList("cassandra.host")
      val cassandraUser: String = configFile.getString("cassandra.username")
      val cassandraKeyspace: String = configFile.getString("cassandra.keyspaces.test")
      val cassandraPassword: String = configFile.getString("cassandra.password")

      newLogger.info("--- Cassandra Parameters ---")
      newLogger.info("cassandraHost: " + cassandraHost.toString)
      newLogger.info("cassandraUser: " + cassandraUser.toString)
      newLogger.info("cassandraKeyspace: " + cassandraKeyspace.toString)
      newLogger.info("cassandraPassword: " + cassandraPassword.toString)

    }
```

So this solution makes my logs look like the following:

```
2375 [main] INFO  c.g.bank.core.utils.GeneralLogger$ - --- Spark Parameters --- 
2449 [main] INFO  c.g.bank.core.utils.GeneralLogger$ - sparkAppName: Flap
```

What I want to accomplish is to have the logs named by the calling class, so if I implement GeneralLogger inside a class named IncomeNotifier I would get the logs this way:

```
2375 [main] INFO  c.g.bank.core.utils.IncomeNotifier$ - --- Spark Parameters --- 
2449 [main] INFO  c.g.bank.core.utils.IncomeNotifier$ - sparkAppName: Flap
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

`super.getClass` just calls supertype's implementation of `getClass`, which is the same as calling your object's `getClass` because you don't (and can't) override it.

`GeneralLogger` as written is a singleton, so you have exactly one `GeneralLogger` and all logs will have the same logger name, so it isn't clear what you mean by

> I implement GeneralLogger inside a class named IncomeNotifier

One option would be

```
class GeneralLogger(clazz: Class[_]) {
  val newLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz)
}
```

In `IncomeNotifier`:

```
val logger = new GeneralLogger(getClass)
logger.CassandraLogger()
```

or define `SparkLogger` and `CassandraLogger` to take the calling class as a parameter.

You *can* get the calling class name without passing it: [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection/2924426#2924426) In most cases you shouldn't.