# Java: Easy way of passing a method as a parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I'm attempting to create a better logging situation for myself. Currently I'm just custom writing a string and logging that string. What I'd like to do instead is know the exact Class#method combination that I'm logging. Currently I'm writing it out such as:

`Logger.push(String s)` where s is something like `"ClassA#myMethod: Successfully implemented database`

What I want to do it make it a little easier on myself, my reducing the text I have to write if possible. I don't want to have to type `ClassA#myMethod`, instead what I want to do is pass a method and use reflection to get the desired names. Here's the example logger function I've created:

```
public static void push(String msg, Method cont){
    logger.info(cont.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + cont.getName() + ": " + msg);
}
```

My issue is with passing the method. Ideally I'm looking for something like `this`, but for the actual method. Currently the only way I could think of is something like:
 `Logger.push("Hello World", getClass().getDeclaredMethods("thisMethodName");`

I was just wondering if there was an easier to get the currently used function. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection is of some use.

Comment: @Thomas ugh I tried to look for all possible sources, but that seems perfect