# Spring AOP: capture method only called from another method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

Guess I have these methods:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {
    private @Autowired Service2 service2;

    public void method1() {
        this.service2.method2();
    }
}

@Service2
public class Service2 {

    public void method2() {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

I'd like to know how to capture `Service2.method2()` call, **when it's called from `Service1.method1())`**.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by capture?

Comment: How to create a pointcut

Comment: I think the AspectJ `cflow` pointcut designator may let you do what you want - inject code on calls to method2 from method1 - but I haven't done this myself (yet :-p).  You would need full AspectJ, not just the subset that is supported directly by Spring aspects.

Comment: I guess you need something like : Java 9 - JEP 259: Stack-Walking API
walk through the answers of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection. you will find it

Comment: @Jordi answered , Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either [use AspectJ from within Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP vis compile-time or load-time weaving and then a pointcut like

```java
execution(* my.package.Service2.method2()) &&
  cflow(execution(* my.package.Service2.method2()))
```

or, similar to what *@Damith* said, use either of

- `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`,
- `new Exception().getStackTrace()` or
- the Java 9 `StackWalker` API

in order to navigate the call stack manually and find the information you are looking for. My suggestion is to use AspectJ, not just because of its elegance but also because of its efficiency.