# Java + Webflux + Resilience4j: Name of the method triggering the fallBack method

Tags: java, resilience4j

Small question regarding Java SpringBoot Webflux with Resilience4J (not Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker) please.

I have the following straightforward:

```
    @TimeLimiter(name = "methodOne", fallbackMethod = "fallbackMethod")
    public Mono<String> methodOne(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8081/serviceBgreeting?name=" + name).build().get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

    @TimeLimiter(name = "methodTwo", fallbackMethod = "fallbackMethod")
    public Mono<String> methodTwo(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8082/anotherMethodTwo?name=" + name).build().get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

And one same callee fallbackMethod, shared by all callers, as:

```
    public Mono<Object> fallBackMethod(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("For debug purpose, I need to know what is the exact method falling back to this fallback method");
        return //the fallback thing needed;
```

What is the best way to retrieve which one of the two methods **methodOne** or **methodTwo** was actually the trigger of this fallback please?

I have some 1000+ methods with this pattern, so I cannot just create 1000+ fallback methods. (like methodOne falls to fallbackOne, methodTwo to fallbackTwo etc..., I cannot)

I am sure there is a smart way to get the method name triggering the fallback.

Tried StackWalker which gives only (fallBackMethod, invoke, fallback, lambda$reactorOnErrorResume$1, onError, etc...) But not the method triggering the fallBack.

A bit of help please.

Thank you

Comment: you want to know if th fallbackMethod is called from `methodOne` or `methodTwo`?

Comment: correct, yes please :)

Comment: Can you check this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection

Comment: tried, and it is not giving the caller (in my case methodOne, methodTwo), but all the intermediates callers (onError, etc :'( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try Executing this from `fallbackMethod`
We are collecting the list of available methods in the executing call and from stack trace checking if the very recent caller is present.

```
Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = throwable.getStackTrace();
Optional<StackTraceElement> first = Arrays.stream(stackTrace)
                .filter(s -> Arrays.stream(methods).anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s.getMethodName())))
                .findFirst();
log.error("Method name Starts here");
first.ifPresent(System.out::println);
log.error("Method name Ends here");
```

This is printing something similar to this

```
in.silentsudo.webapi.services.PaymentOptionService.availablePaymentOptions(PaymentOptionService.java:36)
```

We can extract the method name from here.

This is how my caller looks like

```
@CircuitBreaker(
            name = "payment-option-service-circuit-breaker",
            fallbackMethod = "paymentOptionOnCircuitBreak"
)
public Map<String, List<PaymentOption>> availablePaymentOptions() {
...
}
```