# call methods multiple times with Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Tags: java, methods, stack-trace, super

I have multiple methods for another class which I have to call `times` times.(times is always >0)
I want to do this in another method `doit` by giving it `times` and then it looks where it was called from and calls for example `super.move` the amount of times

```
  @Override
  public void move(int times) {
    doit(times);
  }

  @Override
  public void turnLeft(int times) {
    doit(times);
  }
  @Override
  [...]

public void doit (int t){
  for (int r=-t; r>0; r--)
   super.getDeclaredMethod(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName(), RepetitiveRobotImpl);// ?????
}
```

"`getDeclaredMethod()`" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

"`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()`" [How do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection/421338#421338)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use lambdas? That would require changing your `doit()` method to

```
public void doit(int t, Runnable r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
public void move(int times) {
    doit(times, this::move);
}
```