# get return type of generic method

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I know about type-erasure, I know it shouldn't be possible and every stackoverflow-post answers with workarounds but I'm willing to use the hackiest, bytecode-manipulating, reflective functionality to make this work:

```
static <T> Class<T> getGenericType() {...}
```

Comment: No matter how much you try to hack this: for `getGenericType()` the `T` can be any class, only the caller of `getGenericType()` knows what he expects. If the caller doesn't tell `getGenericType()` what he expects (by providing some hint) the method `getGenericType()` has no way of knowing.

Comment: But isn't it then possible to go up the stack and searching through the caller info?

Comment: You could try the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection to find information about the caller. When using the `StackWalker` you even get the byte code offset where the call occurs. Your code would then somehow need to analyse the byte code after the call to find out what happens there.

Comment: To analyse the byte code you will need to load the class first, which means that you have to find out: which class loader loaded the class? what is the source of the class (where was it loaded from)?

Comment: IMHO this might prove nearly impossible. While good men have said "this is impossible" an someone proved them wrong, the question is whether it is worth the effort needed.

Comment: Believe me, it is :D I live for stuff like this.