# Include stack trace in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I in java add a stacktrace to my debugging printout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882/how-do-i-in-java-add-a-stacktrace-to-my-debugging-printout)

What's the best way to include the stack trace in **log4j**'s output when there's not an exception? The only way I can think of is to create a new `Exception` instance.

```
log.error("description", new Exception());
```

**Follow-up**: I am fully aware of `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and `Thread.dumpStack()`. These output to the console, which in many environments are separate from the log4j output. What I'm looking for a way to log the stack trace to log4j, and not the console.

Comment: Do you want the stack trace of the current thread?

Comment: What is missing from the two solutions you provided by yourself? "doesn't do me any good" is not a very constructive comment.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882. This question asks how to include the stack trace in **log4j**. The "duplicate" question merely outputs the stack trace to standard out. Standard out != log4j output.

Comment: @owlstead I want the stack trace in the log4j output and not standard out.

Answer (score -1):

Steve, I understood that you want the stack trace of the current thread. If so, you can get it by using the `currentThread()` static method of the Thread class and then getting the stack trace. Something like:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

If you want to dump the stack traces of all running threads, you can use the `getAllStackTraces()` static method of the Thread class.

```
Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> stackTraces = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

**Update**

Steve, I tried the `dumpStack()` static method  of Thread class and it uses an empty exeption to perform the dump, so, I think that the way you are doing is correct, or "the best way".

Comment: Yes I'm aware of `getStackTrace()`, but that doesn't do me any good. I want to feed this to log4j.

Comment: I think that the way you are doing is corret. I will update my answer. Wait a moment.

Comment: Uh, can't you just feed the output of e.g. `StackTraceElement.toString()` to log4j? I don't get the question...